# How to debug external libraries in Angular?

Tags: angular, debugging, source-maps

Whenever calling methods/functions from 3rd party libraries such as underscore, Angular will drop you into a bundled vendor.js, source map doesn't seem to work, how to use Chrome Source Devtool to examine the code line by line?

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Press the `prettify` button in the bottom left corner of the minified file. It looks like this `{}`.
[image]

**2.** Put a breakpoint and then refresh and try to hit your breakpoint
[image]

Comment: This only returns index.js:formatted for some reason